# Textures that load automatically in 2.79 do not load in 2.8

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a .blend file from NASA (https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/tess-jpl). When I load it into Blender 2.79, it correctly loads all the accompanying textures:

[image]

In Blender 2.8, however, the textures are not loaded:

[image]

I am new to Blender, so I don't know how I'd even begin to go about troubleshooting this problem. I could work in 2.79, but since I'm a novice I thought it made sense to try learning the new version. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It is not advised to jump versions with the same project

Comment: So if I understand correctly, because the model was likely created with Blender 2.7x, I should use the same version to edit it?

Comment: Yep, it would be possible to do it in 2.8, but you might have to spend one re setting up things like textures

Comment: If you used Blender Render engine an it's materials, then you should stick with 2.79 for editing this model, otherwise you need to convert the materials for new 2.8 engine (which is often even impossible as there is no engine as a direct replacement of Blender Internal)